# Magento 2 - How to create a new custom module API

Tags: magento2, api, security

In Magento 2, How to create custom module API? of course, I need have security? Anyone can help explain with a sample module, thanks!

Comment: http://inchoo.net/magento/api-magento/magento-2-custom-api/ / http://inchoo.net/magento-2/magento-2-api/